# Pandas .loc[] method is too slow, how can I speed it up

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe with 40 million rows,and I want to change some colums by

```
age = data[data['device_name'] == 12]['age'].apply(lambda x : x if x != -1 else max_age)
data.loc[data['device_name'] == 12,'age'] = age
```

but this method is too slow, how can I speed it up.
Thanks for all reply!

Comment: it's probably the `.apply` part that's slow

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna change the first part to :

```
age = data[data['device_name'] == 12]['age']
age[age == -1] = max_age
data.loc[data['device_name'] == 12,'age'] = age
```

you could use, to me more concise(this could gain you a little speed)

```
cond = data['device_name'] == 12
age = data.loc[cond, age]
data.loc[cond,'age'] = age.where(age != -1, max_age)
```

Comment: you are welcome, please let me know if it reduced your execution time

Comment: It seems that .apply() is fast, but .loc[] is slow. Totally not reduce exec time